Maximal number of partitions of vertex
Let $E$ be a finite vertex set of cardinality $n$. Let $F$ be a finite vertex set of cardinality $m$. For each element $x$ in $E$, there are $k$ edges connected to $k$ different elements in $F$. Now we partition $E$ into $E_1, E_2, \dots , E_p,$ and F into $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_q$ such that there is always edge from some element in $E_i$ to some element $F_j$ from each $1\le i\le p$ and $1\le j\le q$. What is the maximal number of the product $pq$?

$mn$, so there must be something I'm not seeing. Are you actually interested in the assignment of the $nk$ edges which minimises the maximum $pq$?

Trivially we have $p\leq n$ and $q\leq k\leq m$. So, if we have the liberty to select edges the answer is $nk$. Just take the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,k}$ with $E$ being one partite set, and $F$ being the other partite set supplemented with $m-k$ isolated vertices.

@MaxAlekseyev Probably I didn't state well my question. I mean for arbitrary $E$ and $F$ what is the maximal number of $pq$. For example $k=2$ $E={a,b,c}$ and $F={x,y,z}$ the edges are ${a-x, a-y, b-x, b-z, c-y, c-z}$. Then the maximal $p=2$ and $q=2$ so $pq$ is not equal to $nk$.

It is still not clear what is given. Are you asking for a formula/algorithm for the maximum $pq$ over all suitable partitions of a given bipartite graph with partite sets $E,F$?

@MaxAlekseyev Yes. I am asking for the formula (in terms of $n,m,k$) or an estimation for the maximum $pq$ over all suitable partitions of a given bipartite graph with partite sets $E$, $F$.

Ok, then $nk$ provides an upper bound as I explained in the comment above. This bound is achievable on certain graphs.
